# Colocando elemento HTML estático como uma extensão para o Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensão

Eu gostaria de fazer uma extensão para o Google Chrome que habilitasse uma barra horizontal que estivesse sempre á disposição na parte superior da janela do usuário. O posicionamento seria algo do tipo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A questão é: como conseguir este comportamento? Pensei em adicionar o arquivo HTML como um `popup` no `browser_action` do arquivo manifest, mas isso fazia ele sumir assim que perdia foco, o que não é bem o que eu desejo. Também pensei em "encaixotar" o código HTML dentro de um Javascript (trocando, ex, `<tag></tag>` por `document.write("<tag></tag>")`, e adicionar no manifest como um `content_script`, mas não consegui fazer aparecer barra nenhuma ao tentar isso. Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

Se o que você quer é ter uma div fixa na parte superior do navegador, você pode usar a regra css [position](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/absrel.php).

Com essa regra você consegue o resultado de que precisa.
Não precisa de javascript nem de browser action, css puro resolve tranquilo.

```css
.barra{
  position: fixed;
  min-width: 100%; /*largura que voce quer*/
  height: 50px; /*altura que voce quer*/
  margin: 0; /* margem que voce quer*/
  padding: 0; /* padding que voce deseja*/
  background: #000;
}
.barra fixa-topo{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="barra fixa-topo"></div>
```

Uma dica importante é você sobrescrever a [newtab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override) padrão do navegador.Nessa newtab é que você coloca o código que você quiser.

No teu manifest.json.

```js
{
  "name": "Nome da extensão",
  "description": "Descrição da extensão",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  
  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "newtab.html"
  },
  "icons": { "128": "icon_128.png" }
  
  
  //demais codigos
 }
```